# Undefined reference to __libc_init_array

Tags: gcc, stm32

I am trying to compile some code for an STM32 chip using CodeBench G++ Lite tools. However, it generates an error.

```
    startup.o: In function `LoopFillZerobss':
(.text.Reset_Handler+0x2a): undefined reference to `__libc_init_array'
```

I have googled and it appears that libc_init_array is probably part of some standard gcc library...but I am not sure how to fix this error?

I also have errors such as this

```
arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find libc.a
```

and similarly for libgcc.a and libm.a

Comment: Check your compiler installation, also add "-v" option to check its library path and make sure there are libraries required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `__libc_init_array` is part of CodeSourcery's 'CS3' mechanism for 'start up' code which ensures all of a programs static initialisation happens before `main` is executed.

Start by ensuring all of the libraries are found. That might be enough to fix all your problems.

One approach is to use arm-none-eabi-g++, and not use arm-none-eabi-ld directly, to do the linking because g++ should correctly pass some important parameters to arm-none-eabi-ld. In some case, that might be all that is needed to find and link the correct libraries.

If you aren't sure how to build on the command line, or arm-none-eabi-g++ isn't doing everything to resolve the missing libraries, go and have a look at LeafLabs web site, where they show how build from the command line using Makefiles
http://leaflabs.com/docs/unix-toolchain.html

They provide a free, Open Source, IDE for STM32, built for Windows, Linux and Mac, which includes a working gcc-based toolchain for each of those platforms, and enough of the libraries to get started http://leaflabs.com/docs/maple-ide-install.html

Even if you'd prefer to use your toolchain for the actual build, it may be worth using theirs, with their Makefiles, to sanity check the process you are using to build your program.

I am not a member of LeafLabs staff, and have no relationship with the company other than I have bought some of their products, and try to answer questions on their forum.